# Redirect to Web Application on Different IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, web, redirect, iis-6

I have a website that is currently running on Windows Server 2003, IIS-6, SQL Server 2000.

The website also has an old ASP.NET application that was purchased commercially. The company has since gone out of business. This is why I have not been able to upgrade to a newer OS all these years.

I have been able to successfully move the site to a new Windows Server but I cannot get the ASP.NET application to work. Everything else works (including SQL integration, etc.)

I must get the new server on-line by March of 2020 because most browsers will no longer recognize TLS 1.0 (this is all Windows Server 2003 will support.)

I was thinking of doing the following...

- Dedicated Host Server running Windows Server 2016
- Hyper-V Virtual Machine running Windows Server 2016 for website
- Hyper-V Virtual Machine running existing Server 2003 for application

I cannot change the landing page of the application. Is it possible to redirect the landing page on the new website to the original target on the old server?

Comment: You just need a reverse proxy (such as nginx), so that browser/proxy connections are TLS 1.2, while proxy/IIS 6 connections remain TLS 1.0.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have never used a reverse proxy but I believe I understand how it works. Do you think it would be possible for me to run the reverse proxy on the HOST Windows Server 2016 and then write rules to direct all traffic to the website VM (also Windows Server 2016) but, for the problematic application I would route the specific URL to the VM running Windows Server 2003?